# Are perturbed FLRW solutions stably causal?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

Consider the most general perturbed FLRW metric, as one typically sees in cosmology textbooks:
$$ds^2 = a^2 (\tau) \left( -(1-2\psi) d\tau^2 + 2 w_i d\tau dx^i + \left[ (1-2\phi)\gamma_{ij} + 2h_{ij} \right] dx^i dx^j \right).$$
Are such solutions stably causal? I am pretty sure that the answer is 'yes', because I am pretty sure that such solutions admit of a global time function (which is equivalent to stable causality). But on the other hand, I'm not sure how to prove rigorously the existence of such a global time function, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by stably causal? The perturbed FLRW metric is not a solution until you solve for the components by putting it in the Einstein's equations with a specific matter sector. So, the answer to your question will depend upon what matter you wish to solve the metric components for.

Comment: I mean in Hawking's sense, which is equivalent to the existence of a global time function---i.e., a scalar field whose gradient is everywhere timelike and future-directed.